# How to know where my site is hosted?

Tags: web-server, hosting, web-hosting, website, web

Hii Experts I want to  know where my website http://www.drpradeepjain.org is 
hosted ?

Please Explain how to know and please explain where to host our website to get best results ....

Comment: NSLookup shows your website is hosted in Dallas, United States, and your IP is 204.197.240.85. Try this link https://www.blacksun.ca/lookup/index.php

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't ask the people you're paying to host your domain?

Answer (score 2):

Your IP address is 204.197.240.85, I got this by looking up your hostname in the DNS.

```
dig www.drpradeepjain.org
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.drpradeepjain.org.  600     IN      A       204.197.240.85
```

A reverse lookup on that IP address shows

```
dig -x 204.197.240.85
; ANSWER SECTION:
85.240.197.204.in-addr.arpa. 21599 IN   PTR     da.datameter.net.
```

Using whois we can see that datameter.net. is Located in New Dehli
however using tcpiputils.com we find that da.datameter.net is located in Dallas, TX which seems consistent. Plugging the IP above into myip.ms also suggests it is in Dallas, TX and shows that your domain ins hosted on the IP.